# Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\Router\dot_array_search() in codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

Hi I am working on Codeigniter 4. I have two server 1st is dev and another is live, Both have php 8.1. I am using Codeigniter 4.2.10. For dev my code is working fine. In live I am getting error: Undefined function dot_array_search(); I checked this function is defined in helper and helper is invoked just above.

`CRITICAL -> Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\Router\dot_array_search()
in SYSTEMPATH/Router/RouteCollection.php on line 1257.

1 SYSTEMPATH/Router/RouteCollection.php(970): CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection->create()

2 SYSTEMPATH/Config/Routes.php(23): CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection->cli()

3 APPPATH/Config/Routes.php(11): require('SYSTEMPATH/Config/Routes.php')

4 SYSTEMPATH/CodeIgniter.php(789): require('APPPATH/Config/Routes.php')

5 SYSTEMPATH/CodeIgniter.php(430): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->tryToRouteIt()

6 SYSTEMPATH/CodeIgniter.php(351): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->handleRequest()

7 FCPATH/index.php(68): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->run()
`
Need help from seniors.

Comment: Navigate to the file at the path: `your-project-root-directory-here/system/CodeIgniter.php`. In that file, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74828387/edit) and share the class property value corresponding to: `public const CI_VERSION = '...'` This will indicate the current framework version.

Comment: I am using CI 4.2.10

Comment: Please, share the **full** error stack trace, not just a part of it.

Comment: Please check in details, I post error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms.
In my case, it was cured by modifying system/helper -> system/Helper.(upper case)